# Vue.js: Laravel Mix not combining files

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with Node.js 6, and Vue.js 2.

In `resources/assets/js/app.js` I have:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));
```

In `webpack.mix.js` I have:

```
mix.combine([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/enhanced.js',
    'resources/assets/js/search.js'
], 'public/js/app.js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

In `resources/assets/js/enhanced.js` I have:

```
require('./app')

var Search = require('./components/Enhanced.vue');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app_page_enhanced',
    render: app_page_enhanced => app_page_enhanced(Page_Enhanced)
});
```

In `resources/assets/js/search.js` I have:

```
require('./app')

var Search = require('./components/Search.vue');

new Vue({
    el: '#app_search',
    render: app_search => app_search(Search)
})
```

I have `npm run watch-poll` running in a Terminal window.

However, I keep getting an error on line 8 of `app.js`:

> require('./bootstrap');

When I comment that line out, the process goes through without additional errors, but when I look at: `public/js/app.js` the separate `.js` files aren't included.

I've tried removing: `require('./app')` from the two `.js` files, and:

```
mix.combine([ ... ], 'public/js/')
```

... and:

```
mix.combine([ ... ], 'public/js/', 'public/js/app.js')
```

... but it made no difference.

It's worth mentioning that the code for Vue works when in the `app.js` file.

I've cobbled this together based on the bits I've scavenged, as I've not been able to find an official guide.

**Update**

In terms of the core problem, @tompec has helped fix it.

However, I thought this would cure the massive number of errors I get when running the [search page](http://www.octintltd.net/) and [featured results page](http://www.octintltd.net/api/get_page_enhanced/1939), where each page is executing the Vue code for both pages, causing the errors.

Comment: Usually `bootstrap.js` imports jquery, lodash and some other libraries needed for your application. Are you sure it's available in the same directory as `app.js`?

Comment: @KiraSan. Yes, it's in the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do something like that

```
mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/enhanced.js',
    'resources/assets/js/search.js'
], 'public/js/app.js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and remove `require('./app')` from `resources/assets/js/enhanced.js` and from `resources/assets/js/search.js`.

And here's the doc: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/tree/master/docs

Comment: You've answered the question (and thank you), so I have to mark it as correct. However, as I've stated in the opening question, there are additional problems, so I'll have to spin that out as a new question.